# git merge --no-commit with edits

Tags: git

If I use

```
git merge --no-commit <other-branch>
```

and then make changes, such as removing files from the merge, is this still a real merge?

I would like the branches to be related (with a merge), but I don't want all of the changes in the  in the new branch.

As a more concrete example, other-branch is a release branch from an older version. The current branch is the develop branch of the current product. We've made some changes for the release branch that should be moved to the develop branch.

We've used cherry-picks in the past, but I feel like there may be an advantage to having git understand a relationship between the two branches.

Is an edited merge still a merge?

Comment: Yes, why not. You will amke git merge --no-commit at first, it merges other_branch with your develop, that you'll remove any files and get changes in index for following commit (remove/change files which you want), but commits from other_branch still in your develop.

Comment: You can also do git merge (including commit), change whatever you want and then git commit --amend to add your changes to you merge-commit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is still a merge.  It doesn't matter whether you run `git merge <other-branch>`, or `git merge --no-commit <other-branch>`, the result will be a merge commit, that has two parents.  The `--no-commit` option simply stops and lets you investigate that the merge went well before you commit the merge.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean by a "true merge". `--no-commit` does allow you the opportunity to introduce additional changes that were not in either parent, so while the commit will still be topologically a merge, it may not be a "true merge" by some definition...

Comment: @twalberg that's typically called an "evil merge".  I assumed that the OP meant a topological merge, since he asked about the "advantage to having git understand a relationship between the two branches".  But you're right that a description like "true" or "real" is imprecise.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, The intent is not to make unrelated changes. I am staying far away from that place. But rather only merging certain files, but not all of them.

Comment: Creating a merge between branches that only merges some of the files (as opposed to a cherry-pick or merge --squash) has the advantage that those files that are merged have a complete history. The history of those files is not truncated at an "unrelated" squash merge.

Answer (score 7):

> The `--no-commit` option simply stops and lets you investigate that the merge went well before you commit the merge.

This is now documented in Git 2.22 (Q2 2019)

See [commit 1ede45e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ede45e44b3b3bef8598ca077a60a6483ede99ae) (21 Feb 2019) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 082c15a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/082c15ade1833e80a65c36d2499676a924d6d6aa), 07 Mar 2019)</sup>

> ### `merge-options.txt`: correct wording of `--no-commit` option
>
> The former wording implied that `--no-commit` would always cause the merge operation to "pause" and allow the user to make further changes and/or provide a special commit message for the merge commit.
>
> **This is not the case for fast-forward merges**, as there is no merge commit
>   to create.
>
> Without a merge commit, there is no place where it makes sense to "stop the merge and allow the user to tweak changes"; doing that would require a full rebase of some sort.
>
> Since users may be unaware of whether their branches have diverged or not, modify the wording to correctly address fast-forward cases as well and suggest using `--no-ff` with `--no-commit` if the point is to ensure that the merge stops before completing.

[The documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1ede45e44b3b3bef8598ca077a60a6483ede99ae/Documentation/merge-options.txt#L6-L13) is clearer:

> With `--no-commit` perform the merge and stop just before creating a merge commit, to give the user a chance to inspect and further tweak the merge result before committing.
>
> Note that fast-forward updates do not create a merge commit and therefore there is no way to stop those merges with `--no-commit`.
>   Thus, if you want to ensure your branch is not changed or updated by the merge command, use `--no-ff` with `--no-commit`.